# The button's background is displayed in the blue color for Android

Tags: android, xml, button, colors, drawable

Dear stackoverflow members, have a good day.

Actually, I want to apply my xml drawable file on a button, so I have used
the attribute background to change it to the designated xml file, but the button is displayed or covered with the blue color !

I have also tried to apply my drawable xml file by using the backgroind-tint attribute, but the background was entirely covered the black color.

Also I have tried to change the default theme applied in my project, but no one of the above methods work fine.

My custom XML design

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval" >
        <gradient android:startColor="#0017ff" android:endColor="#ff0000"
            android:angle="270"
            android:centerX="-1"
            android:type="sweep"
            />
    </shape>
```

The button that I which to change it to my xml drawable design

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:theme="@style/a"
        android:background="@drawable/multi_color_circle_blue_red"

        >


    </Button>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Black and white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

the project manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="cor.example1.srb_2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SRB_2">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The theme xml file

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.SRB_2" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="mystyle" >

    </style>





    <style name="a" >
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="color">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@drawable/eraser</item>

    </style>




</resources>
```

I hope the issue is fully clarified.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix is using
androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton instead of Button

like this

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/a"
    android:background="@drawable/multi_color_circle_blue_red"/>
```